# My code is add +1 at a realtimedatabase everityme that i refresh the page

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I made a code that i read temperatures on the realtime database and classificade them in 3 zones. "Normal :)", "Risco :|" and "Falha :(".

when it goes to Normal for Risco or falha, Numeroalertas get +1 at realtime database. It works well.
But if a im at "Normal :)" and refresh the page, it increases +1 again. And i really dont know how to fix this.

```
  var lastTemperature;
  var alertTriggered = false;


 // Retrieve the last temperature and alert state from the database when the page loads
  var estufaRef = firebase.database().ref("Estufas/Estufa Nike/Dados");
  estufaRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val();
    if (data && data.UltimaTemperatura !== undefined) {
      lastTemperature = data.UltimaTemperatura;
      
      // Only update alertTriggered if it was false before
      if (alertTriggered === false) {
        alertTriggered = data.AlertaAtivado || false;
      }
    }
    
    // Check if Numeroalertas has already been incremented in this session
    var alreadyIncremented = localStorage.getItem("alreadyIncremented") || false;
    if (alertTriggered && !alreadyIncremented) {
      updateAlertState(true);
      localStorage.setItem("alreadyIncremented", true);
    }
  });

 // Update the alert state in the database when the temperature enters or leaves the "Risco :|" zone
  function updateAlertState(alertState) {
    var estufaRef = firebase.database().ref("Estufas/Estufa Nike/Dados");
    estufaRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
      var data = snapshot.val();
      if (data && data.AlertaAtivado !== undefined && data.AlertaAtivado !== alertState) {
        var newNumeroAlertas = data.Numeroalertas || 0;
        if (alertState) {
          newNumeroAlertas++;
        }
        estufaRef.update({
          AlertaAtivado: alertState,
          Numeroalertas: newNumeroAlertas
        });
        // Set the alreadyIncremented flag to true
        localStorage.setItem("alreadyIncremented", true);
      } else {
        estufaRef.update({
          AlertaAtivado: alertState
        });
      }
    });
  }

 function atualizaTemperatura() {
    var currentTemperature = temperaturaArray[temperaturaArray.length - 1].temperatura;
    document.getElementById("temperaturaatual").innerHTML = currentTemperature;
    var zonaAtual = document.getElementById("zonaatual");
    if (currentTemperature <= 50) {
      zonaAtual.innerHTML = "Normal :)";
      zonaAtual.style.color = "green";
      if (alertTriggered) {
        alertTriggered = false;
        updateAlertState(false);
      }
    } else if (currentTemperature > 50 && currentTemperature <= 100) {
      if (currentTemperature !== lastTemperature && currentTemperature > lastTemperature && !alertTriggered) { // Only trigger alert if the current temperature is greater than the last temperature recorded and the alert has not already been triggered
        zonaAtual.innerHTML = "Risco :|";
        zonaAtual.style.color = "orange";
        alertTriggered = true;
        updateAlertState(true);
      } else {
        zonaAtual.innerHTML = "Risco :|";
        zonaAtual.style.color = "orange";
        if (alertTriggered) {
          alertTriggered = true;
          updateAlertState(true);
        }
      }
    } else {
      zonaAtual.innerHTML = "Falha :(";
      zonaAtual.style.color = "red";
      if (alertTriggered) {
        alertTriggered = true;
        updateAlertState(true);
      }
    }
    lastTemperature = currentTemperature; // Update the last temperature
  
    // Print the Numeroalertas value to the HTML page
    var estufaRef = firebase.database().ref("Estufas/Estufa Nike/Dados");
    estufaRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
      var data = snapshot.val();
      var numeroAlertas = document.getElementById("numeroalertas");
      if (data && data.Numeroalertas !== undefined) {
        numeroAlertas.innerHTML = data.Numeroalertas;
      } else {
        numeroAlertas.innerHTML = 0;
      }
    });
  }
  
  setInterval(atualizaTemperatura, 1000);
```

Thats my code.

I hope that we can sole that.

Comment: Your code seems to try and handle this reload condition by storing `alreadyIncremented` in local storage. Did you already step through the code in a debugger, to see: 1) if the value gets stored correctly (so read it back immediately after you write it)? --- 2) if the value gets read correctly when you reload the page?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).